# How to use union in sub query with Access database

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a WinForms application with an Access database.
Please correct me.

```
Select * 
from EMP 
where Empid in 
    (Select id 
     from Test1 
     where pin=4 
     UNION 
     Select id 
     from Test2 
     where pin=4)
```

When I try to execute this on the Access database, it gave me this error:

> Operations are not allowed in subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried as below and its worked.

```
Select * 
from EMP where Empid in (Select id from Test1  where pin=4 ) UNION 
Select * 
from EMP where Empid in(Select id  from Test2  where pin=4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use two standard SQL where conditions, as per below.  I have tested this approach  and it appears to work as expected

```
SELECT x, y, z
WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM b)
AND NOT IN (SELECT x FROM c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Really late but this works

```
Select * 
from EMP 
where Empid in 
    (SELECT id FROM ( 
    Select id from Test1  where pin=4 
    UNION  Select id from Test2 where pin=4 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
Select  e.* 
from    EMP e INNER JOIN
        (
            Select  id 
            from    Test1 
            where   pin=4 
            UNION   
            Select  id 
            from    Test2 
            where pin=4
        ) subSelect ON e.Empid = subSelect.id
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know union operations are not allowed in subqueries,instead you can create a named union query and include in the subquery expression